# Hackerrank Sparse Arrays Solution in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge, array

I've just solved [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays) and I hope you guys give me any feedback to make my code be better.

> Problem: There are *N* strings. Each string's length is no more than 20 characters. There are also *Q* queries. For each query, you are given a string, and you need to find out how many times this string occurred previously.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains *N*, the number of strings. The next *N* lines each
>   contain a string. The *N* + 2nd line contains *Q*, the number of queries. The
>   following *Q* lines each contain a query string.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        String[] stringArr = new String[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                stringArr[i] = scan.next();              
            }

        int q = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                String stringQue = scan.next();

                int occNum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if (stringQue.equals(stringArr[j])) occNum++;                                           
                }
             System.out.println(occNum);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>         String[] stringArr = new String[n];
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
>                 stringArr[i] = scan.next();              
>             }
> ```

Why use an array?  Consider

```
        Map<String, Integer> inputCounts = new HashMap<>(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String input = scan.next();

            Integer count = inputCounts.get(input);
            if (count == null) {
                count = 0;
            }

            count++;
            inputCounts.put(input, count);
        }
```

Now you know the count for each input string.  So

> ```
>                 String stringQue = scan.next();
>
>                 int occNum = 0;
>                 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
>                     if (stringQue.equals(stringArr[j])) occNum++;
>                 }
>              System.out.println(occNum);
> ```

could become just

```
                String query = scan.next();

                Integer count = inputCounts.get(query);
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 0;
                }                          

                System.out.println(count);
```

If the overhead of the hash accesses is less than the overhead of the `for` loop, this might be faster.

A `HashMap` converts the string key into a location in the `Map`.  This is more expensive than a numeric array selection but is probably similar to the cost of the `equals` method.

I think that we can safely say that accessing the `HashMap` is going to be faster than iterating over every member of the array unless the array is tiny.  The larger question is if the cost of building the `HashMap` is going to be greater than the savings in processing the queries.  For a large number of strings and a small number of queries, the cost of building the `HashMap` can outweigh the savings in processing the queries.  That's trivially true if there are zero queries.  And may still be true for one query.  There is some point where it stops being true.  You'd have to benchmark to be sure.

I prefer names like `query` and `count` to `stringQue` and `occNum`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.
I haven't use hashmap structure before so I dont know the benefits of using it instead array. Is it truly faster? When should I use hashmap instead array. Anyway I will find and read some more informations about this kind of data structure. Thank you once again!

Comment: Looping through an array will be slower than just getting a value from a HashMap if the array is large.